# Receiving SIGKILL in UIImage imageNamed

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7

Very recently I have started receiving `SIGKILL`s at this line in my app. This app has worked very well before, without any such errors. I am deploying on iOS 7  now.

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.jpg"];
  UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Also, I do NOT get the KILL every time, but only say every forth or fifth time I run the app.

I know the above snippet perhaps is not sufficient to diagnose or even get a hint on this issue. But I am not sure, what else I need to provide at this moment.

Does anyone has a clue as to what should I try next?

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: Place a breakpoint before these lines and then inspect the code by stepping into the code...at binary level and see if the SIGKILL and check where exactly the error occurs. Is your code inside block?

Comment: is the size of the image is large? ... it may be memory as it is random

Comment: @HaniIbrahim No, it is just 13 KB